# Views: exposed filters for entity reference, do an AND?

Tags: views, 8

I have a View that has exposed filters that searches and returns results for one content type.

I have a few entity reference fields (some content, some taxonomy) that when a user selects multiple values, I want them to be AND'd and limit the result set. It seems that Views is doing `IN ()` no matter what config I set for the filter, which widens the result set as you select more instead of narrowing them down to results that match exactly/only what was selected.

For example, if I have an exposed filter for `field_nodes` and the user checks off 1, 2, 3 and submits, I only want nodes that have 1, 2, AND 3 in that reference field values. Not any node that matches any of the values.